# Enable/Disable for a long time a button depending on a select input

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to create a system of enable and disable of a button in app of a specific user from a list of users, depending on the time selected by a user in "director" role.

The director can chose every how many days enable the template for the basic user:

```
<template name="showSend">
        <h4>Send Notification to: {{data.profile.lastName}} {{data.profile.firstName}}</h4>
        <form>
          <select name="notification">
            <option value="1day">1 day</option>
            <option value="3day">3 days</option>
            <option value="5day">5 days</option>
            <option value="week">1 week</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <label><input type="submit" name={{data.profile.lastName}} id="sendQuest" ><span><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send</span></label>
        </form> 
    </template>
```

On the other hand the user see the button:

```
<template name="dashboard">
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="yes">Yes</button>
...
</template>
```

My users collection is:

```
    Schemas.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema(

  firstName:
    type: String
    optional: true

  lastName:
    type: String
    optional: true

  personNumber:
    type: String
    optional: true


  birthday:
    type: Date
    optional: true


  location:
    type: String
    optional: true

  country:
    type: String
    label: 'Nationality'
    allowedValues: Utils.countryList
    optional: true

  clinic:
    type: String
    label: 'Clinic'
    allowedValues: Utils.clinicList
    optional: true
)

Schemas.User = new SimpleSchema(

  username:
    type: String
    regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/
    optional: true


  emails:
    type: [Object]
    optional: true

  "emails.$.address":
    type: String
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email

  "emails.$.verified":
    type: Boolean

  createdAt:
    type: Date

  profile:
    type: Schemas.UserProfile
    optional: true

  services:
    type: Object
    optional: true
    blackbox: true

  roles:
    type: [String]
    blackbox: true
    optional: true
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? You've given us HTML and a schema - no attempt to actually solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't try because I don't know how to pass this kind of information; 
I've thought that maybe I can pass the info using a collection accessible by both the users involved: so the director set a field in the collection on true and then the user read this true and start the countdown, but how to read this value in realtime? And I don't know how to do code the countdown...

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - Except I'm not actually downvoting you. Just pointing you at why no attempt is not allowed on SO

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

1. You've not attempted to show what you've tried so far.
2. Your explanation isn't quite clear and takes a while to understand what it is that you exactly need.

Based on the above, I cannot share any specific code, but will try to point you in the right direction in order to get you started with this.

**My understanding so far is:**

1. The director can set a timeframe for each user.
2. The user will be able to see the "yes" submit button within that timeframe.

**Your approach can be something like below:**

1. As soon as the director sets the timeframe and submits, you can either have a new field in the `Schemas.UserProfile` with the *expiry date* timestamp (you can calculate this by adding the expiry time to current time to arrive at a future time at which the button will be disabled) OR, you can maintain this data in a new collection (which could contain the userID against the expiry time)
2. In your dashboard template's helper, you can compare the current time vs the expiry time. If you are within the expiry time, then show the button. If not, you may choose to disable that button. (or whatever it is that you want to do, since you've not exactly mentioned that part)